# Rounding up Date and Time to the nearest hour

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, rounding, worksheet-function

I have a column of dates and times. The dates and time column looks like this:

```
01/01/2013 08:20
01/01/2013 08:55
```

How do I round up the times from this column to the nearest hour bearing in mind it also has the date in the column?

Answer (score 3):

As per pnuts' suggestion, I'll post this:

```
=CEILING(A1,"1:00")
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
=INT(ROUNDUP(A1*24,0))/24
```

if your dates/times are not text.

Comment: Alternatively `=CEILING(A1,"1:00")`

Comment: @userNaN agree with pnuts. There are a lot of formula in excel which does things directly but has not receive much attention.